# Is it code-legal to backfeed both legs of a 240V panel from a 120V portable generator?

Tags: electrical-panel, code-compliance, generator

My question is very similar to this one ([Can I plug a 120 volt generator into a 240 transfer switch with a modified cord/connector?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/134153/can-i-plug-a-120-volt-generator-into-a-240-transfer-switch-with-a-modified-cord)), but I'd like to know whether DDS's answer is code-legal under the 2014 NEC.

To make sure it's clear what I'm asking about, I'd like to use a 120V portable generator to feed a 120/240V panel. There are no 240V loads, so I would like to simply install an interlock between the main breaker and the backfeed breaker to avoid installing an entire transfer switch panel. The loads throughout the building are within range for the generator, so I'm not worried about overloading it, but I would like for both busbars in the panel to receive power. I would use a 2-pole breaker, but both screw terminals would connect to the same wire from the generator.

Is this code-legal?

Comment: Is there a service connected to this panel already?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes. I would be using an interlock plate to prevent islanding

Comment: Is having the meter pulled for the duration an option?

Comment: They do make interlock kits that lock out your main breaker and allow a backfed breaker to be used. But tying both busses together I would just move the needed loads to the same leg ie all odd or all even.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel No, because this is for someone who isn't quite as electrically-savvy.

Comment: @EdBeal I know I can get the interlock. The question is about tying the busses. I don't know if I can easily move loads

Comment: As long as it is interlocked it should not be a problem because it would be isolated. Moving loads would be safer, I always have a couple of inches extra wire so I can balance the service but some cut very short, I would try, just the idea of something going wrong is scary.

Comment: What does the generator in question use for its built-in circuit breakers?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Push button breakers. I'd be using the L5-30R on the generator, which has a matching 30A internal breaker.

Comment: @HariGanti -- does the panel have 2 spare spaces in it, come to think of it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Not actually sure... At this point, we decided on a 120/240V inverter, which has an L14-30 that (I hope) can provide split-phase 120/240. If the panel doesn't have space, I'll be adding a subpanel or replacing the main.